# Отобразить ссылку в UITextView

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextview

Есть UiTextView который с сервера может принимать текст + ссылки HTML вида `<a href="https://apple.com">гиперссылка</a>` Ссылка может быть в любом месте текста (в начале ,в середине, конце), так же ссылка может быть и не одна. Нужно обработать текст так, чтобы в iOS отображались они как гиперссылка

я нашел как сделать гиперссылку, не могу понять как заменить HTML код в тексте на гиперссылки
Вот как формирую гиперлинк в objective - c

```
  NSMutableAttributedString * seeMore = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Learn more"];
    [seeMore addAttribute: NSLinkAttributeName value: @"http://google.com/" range: NSMakeRange(0, seeMore.length)];

    [cell.textView setAttributedText:seeMore];
```

Comment: Не совсем понял, `<a href="https://apple.com">гиперссылка</a>` вы хотите сделать кликабельным, что бы можно было перейти на страницу и в тексте было видно только `гиперссылка`?

Comment: @Fidel Совершенно верно. В андроиде автоматом обрабатывает сообщения вида `<a href="https://apple.com">гиперссылка</a>`
а iOS только www.apple.com

Comment: Есть пару решений, по вашему вопросу, одно громоздкое - костыльно - велосипедное, а другое ... Ну собственно вот вам [решение](https://cocoapods.org/?q=OHAttributedStringAdditions)

Comment: Да и еще, можете использовать как через менеджер зависимостей, либо просто взять все с `Github` и закинуть к себе в проект.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655798/links-in-uitextview-add-and-custom